# Introduce bar progress bar into upload file

Tags: php, progress-bar

I've got  a problem for introduce a bar progress.When I click on submit, I want a progress bar that appears in the tag progress until the page is directed to another page to say "The message has been sent"
Here is an excerpt from my code :

```
<?php
define('MB', 1048576);
$today = getdate();
$nb =$today[0];
$extensions = array('.rar','.zip'); 
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['userfile']['name'], '.');
echo '<pre>';
    $nomFichier= $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $info = pathinfo($nomFichier);
    $file_name =$nb.'.'.$info['extension'];
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir .$file_name;

    if(in_array($extension, $extensions)){ 
    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < 100*MB){
    if (mail($mail,$sujet,$message,$header) AND move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']      ['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
                                                echo 'The message has been sent'."\r\n";
                                            echo "The file is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
                                                echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
                                                echo '<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" OnClick="window.location.href=\'service.php\'">Return</button></div>';
}           

}
... ?>
```

here is the form in question, which sends the data to the previous function

```
<?php
echo    '<form role="form" method="post" action="envoiService2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="nom">
                            </div>

                            <<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                                <input type="file" id="fileControl" value="label" name="userfile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <p class="help-block">Only ".rar" or ".zip" format </p>
                            </div>


                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="uploadFile()" name="uploadFiles" value="Upload the files">Send</button>
                        </form>

                        <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="0">
                            </progress>
                        <div id="percentageCalc">
                        </div>';

                echo    '</div>'; ?>
```

How can I put a progress bar in this code, please ?

Comment: With PHP only you can't. The only way to do that is to use Flash for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Ajax Upload Progress Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878161/php-ajax-upload-progress-bar)